# FCM message not queueing for disconnected device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

if user shut down the device, message with data payload is not delivered to device once device is online again. when I query FCM status for the device token on google play console, message status is "accepted" and does not change after device is online and there is a device disconnected event prior to the accepted event.
when using FCM console to send a push message in same scenario, the log show device reconnected and message get delivered after device is turned on again.

How to make message delivered for messages that I send from server to device when it is switched off and later on again. Notice that this only happen if device is shut down. if I close all data connections like flight mode, messages get delivered once online again.